# Reshaping Feature using QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, editing

In my job are currently looking for a ArcGIS free alternative, we try QGIS but ArcGIS reshape feature  is very important for us when working with curves. What we do basically is:

We've a line as marked in the red square bellow;

[image: qgis]

then we select two point of that line as show in the next picture;

[image]

and the final result is the geometry reshaped as show in this final picture;

[image]

Is there any feature or plugin in QGIS for accomplish this behavior?

Answer (score 17):

In QGIS you have a reshape tool: *Reshape Feature* in the Advance Digitising Toolbar. This is the icon of the tool  [image]

Like in ArcGIS, selecting the line that you want to reshape, use the tool to draw the new segment and right-click to confirm.

[image]

[image]